# How do I replace an array's element?

Tags: ruby, arrays

How can I substitue an element in an array?

```
a = [1,2,3,4,5]
```

I need to replace 5 with `[11,22,33,44].flatten!`

so that `a` now becomes

```
a = [1,2,3,4,11,22,33,44]
```

Comment: please give us an explanation as to why you are needing to do this and in what context this is

Comment: might want to change the title to how do I substitute array elements in a ruby 'each' style iterator

Answer (score 45, accepted):

Not sure if you're looking to substitute a particular value or not, but this works:

```
a = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
b = [11, 22, 33, 44]
a.map! { |x| x == 5 ? b : x }.flatten!
```

This iterates over the values of `a`, and when it finds a value of `5`, it replaces that value with array `b`, then flattens the arrays into one array.

Comment: While this does work, it's overly complicated for what the original poster is trying to do. Using array-slicing to replace a range is a more straight-forward and simple solution. See [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/1704805/456814).

Comment: @Ryan McGeary I need a same method except the value of 5 I want to replace all numbers in the array divisible by 3 with a word "BINGO". How to do that. I tried `ary = (0..100).to_a ary.map!{|i| i % 3 == 0 ? i : "BINGO" }` It replaces all except those divisible by 3

Answer (score 19):

Perhaps you mean:

```
a[4] = [11,22,33,44] # or a[-1] = ...
a.flatten!
```

A functional solution might be nicer, how about just:

```
a[0..-2] + [11, 22, 33, 44]
```

which yields...

```
=> [1, 2, 3, 4, 11, 22, 33, 44]
```

Comment: +1 Thanks! The functional solution was more adaptable to when I wanted to replace a single element by two values at a variable location in the array, i.e.:  a[0..b-1] + [val1, val2] + [b+1..-1]

Answer (score 14):

The version of [bta](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1704755/how-do-i-replace-an-arrays-element#answer-1704831) using a.index(5) is the fastest one:

```
a[a.index(5)] = b if a.index(5) # 5.133327 sec/10^6
```

At least 10% faster than [Ryan McGeary](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1704755/how-do-i-replace-an-arrays-element#answer-1704833)'s one:

```
a.map!{ |x| x == 5 ? b : x } # 5.647182 sec/10^6
```

However, note that a.index(5) only return the first index where 5 is found.
So, given an array where 5 appears more than once, results will be different:

```
a = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 5]
b = [11,22,33,44]

a[a.index(5)] = b if a.index(5)
a.flatten # => [1, 2, 3, 4, 11, 22, 33, 44, 5]

a.map!{ |x| x == 5 ? b : x }
a.flatten # => [1, 2, 3, 4, 11, 22, 33, 44, 11, 22, 33, 44]
```

Answer (score 7):

[Array#delete](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-1.9.3/Array.html#method-i-delete) will return the item or nil. You may use this to know whether or not to push your new values

```
a.push 11,22,33,44 if a.delete 5
```

Comment: This is very clean, nice job!

Answer (score 5):

You really don't have to flatten if you just concatenate.  So trim the last element off the first array and concatenate them:

```
a = [ 1, 2, 3, 4, 5 ]           #=> [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
t = [11, 22, 33, 44]            #=> [11, 22, 33, 44]
result = a[0..-2] + t           #=> [1, 2, 3, 4, 11, 22, 33, 44]
```

a[0..-2] is a slice operation that takes all but the last element of the array.

Hope it helps!

Answer (score 5):

This variant will find the `5` no matter where in the array it is.

```
a = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
a[a.index(5)]=[11, 22, 33, 44] if a.index(5)
a.flatten!
```

Answer (score 2):

Here is another simple way to replace the value `5` in the array:

```
a[-1, 1] = [11, 22, 33, 44]
```

This uses the [`Array#[]=`](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-2.1.1/Array.html#method-i-5B-5D-3D) method. I'm not exactly sure why it works though.

Answer (score 0):

gweg, not sure what you're trying to do here, but are you looking for something like this?

```
a = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
a.delete_at(4)
a = a.concat([11,22,33,44])
```

There are a number of ways of doing this -- I don't think the code above is especially nice looking. It all depends on the significance of '5' in your original array.